# problems filling an array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I parsed a json and I'm trying to take 2 values for each element from the json and put them in a array the problem is that I want to put the values into the array like a single element "array" example:

```
[
 { name: 'name1', elements: [ 'elem1' ] },
 { name: 'name2', elements: [ 'elem2', 'elem3' ] }
]
```

I tried 2 ways.

the first is this:

```
function getMonsters(json) {
    var monsters = [];
    var monster = {};
    json.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === "large") {
            monster['name'] = element.name;
            monster['elements'] = element.elements;
            monsters.push(monster);
        }
    });
    return monsters;
}
```

the problem with the first way is that it always returns the same 2 values:
[image: response image]

the second way is this:

```
function getMonsters(json) {
    var monsters = [];
    var monster = {};
    json.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === "large") {
            monsters.push(element.name, element.elements);
        }
    });
    return monsters;
}
```

but the problem with the second way is that it returns each monster and element separately and not like in my example:
[image: response image]

this is the json if u want to check : https://mhw-db.com/monsters

Answer (score 2):

You are reusing the `monster` object every iteration in your first example. Either move the declaration of `var monster = {}` into the loop or, better yet, just push an object literal.

```js
function getMonsters(json) {
  const monsters = [];

  json.forEach(({ elements, name, type }) => {
    if (type === "large") {
       monsters.push({ name, elements });
    }
  });

  return monsters;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt is almost correct. The reason why all of the items in the array end up being the same object is because `monster` is the same reference in all of the array items. You need a new instance of `monster` on every iteration. Just put your initialization of `monster` in your loop

```js
function getMonsters(json) {
var monsters = [];
json.forEach(element => {
    if (element.type === "large") {
        var monster = {};
        monster['name'] = element.name;
        monster['elements'] = element.elements;
        monsters.push(monster);
    }
});
return monsters;
```